# Displaying a loading gif for 5 seconds automatically

Tags: javascript

I want to display a loading gif automatically when the user goes to the website and then after 5 seconds it goes away.

I found this script which does what I want, but it does not do it automatically. The user needs to click on the button to start it which kind of defeats the purpose.

```
<input type = "button" value = "Show image for 5 seconds" onclick = "show()"><br><br>
<div id = "myDiv" style="display:none"><img id = "myImage" src = "images/ajax-loader.gif"></div><br>

<script type = "text/javascript">

function show() {
    document.getElementById("myDiv").style.display="block";
    setTimeout("hide()", 5000);  // 5 seconds
}

function hide() {
    document.getElementById("myDiv").style.display="none";
}

</script>
```

If there is any way in which I can do this, or if there is a better way of doing it please just comment.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Just remove the `onclick="show()"`, and add `show();` as the last line of your JavaScript block.

Also, as I'm sensitive to [global namespace pollution](http://blogger.ziesemer.com/2007/10/respecting-javascript-global-namespace.html), I'd do it like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  (function(){
    var myDiv = document.getElementById("myDiv"),

      show = function(){
        myDiv.style.display = "block";
        setTimeout(hide, 5000); // 5 seconds
      },

      hide = function(){
        myDiv.style.display = "none";
      };

    show();
  })();

</script>
```

Comment: Remember though if he is loading this in the head of the page his divs do not exist in the dom. Prob best to do it on page load.

Comment: @DominicGreen - agreed, but this will work with the sample he showed.  Otherwise, I'd call the entire thing from something like `jQuery.ready()`.

Comment: @connor.p Is see no reason to first hide the div with CSS, and then show it again immediately using JavaScript. I added an example that avoids that.

Comment: @ChristoferEliasson - Agreed, and +1 for your answer - especially for its simplicity.  However, the approach here would allow for the image to be re-shown if later required.

Comment: @ziesemer I agree, I could declare my function outside the timeout and name it instead of making it anonymous. So if he intend to reuse the function, he should definitely do that.

Comment: @DominicGreen Doesn't waiting for the on page load event defeat the purpose of the loading gif?  It seems for this to work as intended the div needs to be declared early on the page and show() should be called immediately thereafter...or am I missing something...?

Answer (score 5):

You can just remove the `display: none;` from myDiv. That way it will be visible from the beginning, and then you hide it after five seconds.

There is no need to first hide it with CSS, and then display it with JavaScript, when you want it to show up from the beginning.

```
<input type = "button" value = "Show image for 5 seconds" onclick = "show()"><br><br>
<div id = "myDiv"><img id = "myImage" src = "images/ajax-loader.gif"></div><br>

<script type = "text/javascript">   
setTimeout(function(){
   document.getElementById("myDiv").style.display="none";
}, 5000);  
</script>
```

Comment: What if the user has Javascript disabled?  Then you'll show them a loading animation, and then the script will never remove it.

Answer (score 3):

Get rid of the image's `style="display:none"` so that the image appears by default. Others are telling you to call `show()` first, but that's *completely unnecessary*. **You don't need to use JavaScript to initially show the image; just let it display on its own.** Then, remove it after 5 seconds have passed:

```
<div id = "myDiv"><img id = "myImage" src = "images/ajax-loader.gif"></div><br>

<script type = "text/javascript">
    setTimeout(function() {
        document.getElementById("myDiv").style.display="none";
    }, 5000);  // 5 seconds
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried window.onload?

Something along the lines of:

```
<body onload="show();">
..snip
</body>
```

Comment: now i haven't, i've never heard of it maybe it will be worth looking into

Answer (score 1):

Put this right after `<body>`

```
<div id="myDiv"><img id="myImage" src="images/ajax-loader.gif"></div>
<script>
    setTimeout('document.getElementById("myDiv").style.display="none"', 5000);  // 5 seconds
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `window.onload = show;` to the end of your script and it will show the loader as soon as the page has finished loading.  You'll want to use this event for anything you want to do when the user opens the page, as it makes sure the entire page is available before trying to manipulate elements on the page.

Answer (score 0):

Was looking for something similar to this recently for a project but not using an image, using css, html and a bit of js. The page used was dummy page used purely for a pass through loader.
Site is build on Bootstrap 3.3.7

```js
<!-- JS - Place in Head Tags -->
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript"><!--
/* Countdown seconds */
var count = 5;
/* Web Page to redirect with Linked PHP/Bootstrap Alert Box */
var url = "index.php?s=1";
/* Call function at specific intervals */
var countdown = setInterval(function() { 
    /* Display Countdown with txt */
    $('#displayTimer').text("Redirection in: " + count-- + " seconds");
    /* If count is smaller than 0 ...*/
    if (count < 0) {
        $('#displayTimer').text("Redirecting now....");
        /* Clear timer set with setInterval */
        clearInterval(countdown);
        /* Redirect */
        $(location).attr("href", url);
   } 
    // milliseconds
}, 1000);
</SCRIPT>
<!-- JS - Place in Head Tags -->
```

```css
/*Loader CSS */
#circle {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
 width: 150px;
    height: 150px; 
}
.loader {
    width: calc(100% - 0px);
 height: calc(100% - 0px);
 border: 8px solid #162534;
 border-top: 8px solid #09f;
 border-radius: 50%;
 animation: rotate 5s linear infinite;
}
@keyframes rotate {
100% {transform: rotate(360deg);}
}
/*Loader CSS */
```

```html
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Loader Code - 4 Circles - Place In Body -->
<div id="circle">
  <div class="loader">
    <div class="loader">
        <div class="loader">
           <div class="loader">

           </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- Loader Code - 4 Circles -->
```

Code gives 4 Circles with a rotating bar one inside the other

Does not show an error when in use